# Can I open a existing project on c++ builder version 26.0.36039.7899?

Tags: c++, builder

I installed c++ builder 10.3 community edition 26.0.36039.7899 in this September and have been using it for a month by loading a project XXX.cbproj from recently used project list. When I tried to load another project YYY.cbproj from previously used project list, however, it cannot be found. It was not found in Windows Explorer too. Instead I fond __astcache folder, within which two folders @c@@program files (x86)@embarcadero@studio@20.0@bin and c@@program files (x86)@embarcadero@studio@20.0@bin exist with no YYY.cbproj.

Curiously, the folder for recently used project XXX.cbproj has the same structure above  with no XXX.cbproj, but it can be loaded.

I am very happy to know how YYY.cbproj can be loaded from previously used project list.

Comment: If it's not there when you use Windows  Explorer, there is no way for the IDE to load it. It can't load a project that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The "previously used project list" is just a list of names (paths).

It doesn't actually contain projects.

If Windows Explorer doesn't show you the project, then it's no longer on your hard drive, so there's nothing for C++ Builder 10.3 Community Edition 26.0.36039.7899 to load.

You'll have to restore the project from backups, or get it again from wherever you got it last time (as appropriate).

Comment: I could have found a backup of my project. I don't know why my several projects were erased. But I can go forward. Thanks a lot!